# Why java.lang.Object class methods are native?

Tags: java, object, native

These are some methods in `java.lang.Object` class, I was going through...

```
 protected native Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException;

 public final native Class<?> getClass();

 public native int hashCode();

 public final native void notify();

 private static native void registerNatives();

 public final native void wait(long timeout) throws InterruptedException;
```

why are these methods define as native? Please share reference and further reading docs if possible.

Source : [java.lang.Object](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Object.java#Object.hashCode%28%29)

Comment: Last one does not exist. Any reason why they shouldn't be native?

Comment: @EJP updated. Also the above link explain what is `native`. Im asking why `native`.

Comment: @EJP Idk, frankly speaking, Im  not an expert about `native` thats why I want to know some strong reason for it.

Comment: Read the duplicate, you will understand what is it, then you could guess why they could be natives (for some at least).